# How do I seed the rand() function in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, c, random, srand

Part of what I'm developing is a random company name generator. It draws from several arrays of name parts. I use the `rand()` function to draw the random name parts. However, **the same "random" numbers are always generated in the same sequence every time** I launch the app, so the same names always appear.

So I searched around SO, and in C there is an `srand()` function to "seed" the random function with something like the current time to make it more random - like `srand(time(NULL))`. Is there something like that for Objective-C that I can use for iOS development?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The functions `rand()` and `srand()` are part of the Standard C Library and like the rest of the C library fully available for you to us in iOS development with Objective-C. Note that these routines have been superseded by `random()` and `srandom()`, which have almost identically calling conventions to `rand()` and `srand()` but produce much better results with a larger period. There is also an `srandomdev()` routine which initializes the state of the random number generator using the random number device. These are also part of the Standard C Library and available for use on iOS in Objective-C.

Answer (score 30):

Why don't you use `arc4random` which doesn't require a seed? You use it like this:

```
int r = arc4random();
```

[Here's](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/random-thoughts-rand-vs-arc4random.html) an article comparing it to `rand()`. The `arc4random()` man page says this about it in comparison to `rand()`:

> The arc4random() function uses the key stream generator employed by the arc4 cipher, which uses 8*8 8
>        bit S-Boxes.  The S-Boxes can be in about (2**1700) states.  The arc4random() function returns pseudo-
>        random numbers in the range of 0 to (2**32)-1, and therefore has **twice the range of rand(3)** and
>        random(3).

If you want a random number within a range, you can use the `arc4random_uniform()` function. For example, to generate a random number between 0 and 10, you would do this:

```
int i = arc4random_uniform(11);
```

Here's some info from the man page:

> arc4random_uniform(upper_bound) will return a uniformly distributed random number less than upper_bound. arc4random_uniform() is recommended over constructions like ``arc4random() % upper_bound'' as it avoids "modulo bias" when the upper bound is not a power of two.

Comment: Technically @torrey.lyons answered my question more directly, but I definitely prefer arc4random rather than srand(). Thanks